# How can I call mutation in GraphQL playground?

Tags: graphql, mutation, graphql-mutation, graphql-playground

My schema looks like this within the yellow coloured square in the image below
[image]

And the code on the left side doesn't really work.
How can I call this in GraphQL playground?

Appreciate your answer in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you can do input QUERY VARIABLES like

```
{ 
 "input": {
    "scheduleId: "123",
    "reason": "123"
 }
}
```

2. also you can input variables to directly

```
mutation {
 cancelScheduleByAdmin(input: {
    "scheduleId": "123",
    "reason": "123"
 }) {
   ...
 }
}
```